# How to find accurate LatLng values of google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In my App,user can find place Name using `click` event,after getting place Name,I am showing the place name to user with `inputField`For this I written the following code.

//helper function

```
function makingGeocodeRequest(obj,callback){
   var geocodeInstance=new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocodeInstance.geocode(obj,callback);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(mapInstane,"click",function(event){
 makingGeocodeRequest(_.object(["location"],[event.latLng]),
                        function(res,status){
                            document.getElementById("field").value=res[0]["formatted_address"];
                        }
 )
})
```

Once user click on `Save` button.I am finding `latlng` value based on place Name.using the following code

```
makingGeocodeRequest(
    _.object(["address"],[document.getElementById("field").value]),
    function(res,status){
        if (status===google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latLngObj=res[0]["geometry"]["location"];
          console.log(latLngObj;
        }
    }
)
```

The problem here,both `latlng` values are different(click event time latlng value and save button action latlng value).

Actually both are finding from `Google`,but it's returning different latlng values.

While click event event,I am changing cursor style with [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dac7rqiscpkv7i/add.svg) Icon.After click on `Save` button reverting default cursor.

How can I fix this.Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you create the marker(do you use a custom marker-image)?

Comment: @Dr.Molle Yes I am using custom markerImage.

Comment: adjust the position of the image via the `anchor`-option of the marker. The default-anchor is the bottom-middle of the image(I guess your image needs another anchor, hard to say without seeing the image)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I added Icon,What I used for marker and cursor style.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I updated question.can you check it once.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can create and array of points, add marker to this array and render results of the array on the map.

Here is how you can do this :

With Javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var markersList= [];

        function initGMap()
        {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39, 20);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            // add a click event handler to the map object and get the lat Lng and then place it on the map
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event)
            {
                // place a marker
                placeMarker(event.latLng);

                // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
                document.getElementById("latVal").value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById("lngVal").value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
        }
        // here is the function to place Marker on the map
        function placeMarker(location) {
            // first remove all markers if there are any
            deleteOverlays();

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location, 
                map: map
            });

            // add marker in markers array
            markersList.push(marker);

            //map.setCenter(location);
        }

        // Here you can use this function to delete all markers in the array
        function deleteOverlays() {
            if (markersList) {
                for (i in markersList) {
                    markersList[i].setMap(null);
                }
            markersList.length = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

With Html code,

```
<body onload="initGMap()">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <input type="text" id="latVal">
    <input type="text" id="lngVal">
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to set the position of the image as far as the center of the coordinates ?